# put a symbol after word enclosed in h3 or span in the same line with css

Tags: html, css

I have crafted a webpage. It has many words enclosed in spans and h3 tags. Now I am trying to put some symbols at the end of text on the same line using CSS class. I can do this with class something like below using background-image property:

```
    .newtohtml5{
        width:fit-content;         
        background-image:url(http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:2%;
        background-position-x:right;               
    }
```

However the problem with this class is that the HTML5 symbol appears at the end of the line leaving huge space between the text and symbol itself. I want that symbol appear exactly after the text in the span on the same line, not at the end of the line having huge space between the text and the symbol.

I will not like to make any changes to HTML. Though any solution is appreciated. But CSS only trick will be great.

Comment: shouldnt display-style:inline; do the trick?

Comment: @toxicate20 you mean display:inline; No that's for controlling line breaks; and btw span is inline displayed by default;

Comment: The title does not say it all. You included no markup, and you did not describe why you are using artificial and not widely supported constructs, instead of just setting a right padding that matches the image width. (The question also arises why the images are not part of content.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry for inexperienced knowledge, but which constructs I should ideally be using in such scenarios. Consider that I know the text will only span line and there will definitely some space at the end of the line to fit the symbol. Then how should I position the symbol right after the text? The markup could be simple span:`<span class="newtohtml5">text here</span> <br/>` followed by line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't require full cross-browser support, and are okay using only those browsers that implement CSS3 generated content *and* you want that generated content to appear immediately after the text contained within the `span`, you can use the `::after` pseudo-element:

```
<span class="newtohtml5">text here</span> <br/>
```

With the CSS:

```
.newtohtml5::after {
    content: ' (generated content).'
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4jdR8/).

It's worth noting that this generated content is after the content of the `span`, but still *within*, and a part of, the `span` itself.

You can also use attributes of the element to include in the generated content, for example, with the following CSS you can include the string contained within the `class` attribute:

```
.newtohtml5::after {
    content: ' (.' attr(class) ').';
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4jdR8/1/).

You can also insert images into the `content` property:

```
.newtohtml5::after {
    content: url(http://lorempixel.com/25/25);
    margin-left: 1em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4jdR8/2/).

Comment: And what if I want to add more than one symbol corresponding to each class specified on the element